# For Each, next value before Next

Tags: vb.net, foreach

I am wondering if I could get the value of the Next value in the For Each before the Next statement

If I have this code:

```
For Each i As String In myStringArray
   'Do Something with i
Next
```

Can I have something similar, only I am doing or checking the next value:

```
For Each i As String In myStringArray
   'Do Something with i
   'Check the Next Value of i
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the opposite and keep the last item, but act on it:

```
Dim last As String = Nothing

For Each i As String In myStringArray
    If last IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Treat last as current, i as next
    End If

    last = i
Next
```

Comment: +1 Because if possible (depending on surrounding code) this is a cleaner solution then a index loop based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `for each` loop, use a `for` loop and index into the array.

```
For index As Integer = 0 To myStringArray.Length
    ...
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

No not in a for each, but you could use index instead if it is a Array

```
For i As Integer = 0 To myStringArray.Length - 1
    Dim s As String = myStringArray(i)
    'Do Something with s
    If i - 1 < myStringArray.Length Then
        Dim nexts as String = myStringArray(i + 1)
        'Check the Next Value of s = nexts
    End If
Next
```